# Как при печати таблицы из QTableWidget задать размер колонок и изменить их внешний вид

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtablewidget, qprintpreviewdialog

Я отправляю на печать таблицу созданную из `QTableWidget` и заголовок к ней, который почему-то появляется снизу.

Подскажите, можно ли как то установить заголовок на самый вверх документа, далее пропустить строчку и после этого только выводить таблицу. 
А также, можно ли как то изменить вид рамок таблицы и изменять размер столбцов при печати, т.к. они всегда  подгоняются под размер содержимого или подскажите куда двигаться.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtPrintSupport
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont
from PyQt5.QtPrintSupport import QPrinter


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(519, 447)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 70, 431, 241))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(15)
        self.tableWidget.setFont(font)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(2)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(3)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(1, 0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(1, 1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(2, 0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(2, 1, item)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setMinimumSectionSize(62)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 340, 431, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 30, 181, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(13)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "2"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "3"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Column 1"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Column 2"))
        __sortingEnabled = self.tableWidget.isSortingEnabled()
        self.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(False)
        item = self.tableWidget.item(0, 0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Test row 1 col 1"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(0, 1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Test row 1 col 2"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(1, 0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Test row 2 col 1"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(1, 1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Test row 2 col 2"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(2, 0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Test row 3 col 1"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(2, 1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Test row 3 col 2"))
        self.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled)
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Preview/Print"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Print Table Widget"))


class PrintTableWidget(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        # делаем ресайз колонок
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(200)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.handlePreview)


    def handlePrint(self):
        dialog = QtPrintSupport.QPrintDialog()
        if dialog.exec_() == QtWidgets.QDialog.Accepted:
            printer = QPrinter(QPrinter.HighResolution)
            printer.setPaperSize(QPrinter.A4)
            self.handlePaintRequest(dialog.printer())

    def handlePreview(self):
        dialog = QtPrintSupport.QPrintPreviewDialog()
        dialog.paintRequested.connect(self.handlePaintRequest)
        dialog.exec_()

    def handlePaintRequest(self, printer):
        document = QtGui.QTextDocument()
        document.setPlainText("Заголовок") # <-- нужно перенести наверх как заголовок
        # устанавливаем размер текста по умолчанию
        font = QFont('Arial', 18)
        document.setDefaultFont(font)
        cursor = QtGui.QTextCursor(document)
        table = cursor.insertTable(self.tableWidget.rowCount(), self.tableWidget.columnCount())
        for row in range(table.rows()):
            for col in range(table.columns()):
                it = self.tableWidget.item(row, col)
                if it is not None:
                    cursor.insertText(it.text())
                cursor.movePosition(QtGui.QTextCursor.NextCell)
        document.print_(printer)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ptw = PrintTableWidget()
    ptw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте **`insertHtml`**.

> void QTextCursor::**insertHtml**(const QString &html)
>
> Вставляет текст `html` в текущую position().
>
> Текст интерпретируется как HTML.
> Примечание. При использовании этой функции с таблицей стилей таблица стилей
> будет применяться только к текущему блоку в документе.
> Чтобы применить таблицу стилей ко всему документу,
> используйте вместо нее QTextDocument::setDefaultStyleSheet().

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextcursor.html#insertHtml

---

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtPrintSupport
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont
from PyQt5.QtPrintSupport import QPrinter


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(519, 447)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 70, 431, 241))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(15)
        self.tableWidget.setFont(font)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(2)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(3)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(1, 0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(1, 1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(2, 0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(2, 1, item)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setMinimumSectionSize(62)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 340, 431, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 30, 181, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(13)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "2"))
        item = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "3"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Column 1"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Column 2"))
        __sortingEnabled = self.tableWidget.isSortingEnabled()
        self.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(False)
        item = self.tableWidget.item(0, 0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Test row 1 col 1"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(0, 1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Test row 1 col 2"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(1, 0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Test row 2 col 1"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(1, 1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Test row 2 col 2"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(2, 0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Test row 3 col 1"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(2, 1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Test row 3 col 2"))
        self.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled)
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Preview/Print"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Print Table Widget"))


class PrintTableWidget(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        # делаем ресайз колонок
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(200)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.handlePreview)

    def handlePrint(self):
        dialog = QtPrintSupport.QPrintDialog()
        if dialog.exec_() == QtWidgets.QDialog.Accepted:
            printer = QPrinter(QPrinter.HighResolution)
            printer.setPaperSize(QPrinter.A4)
            self.handlePaintRequest(dialog.printer())

    def handlePreview(self):
        dialog = QtPrintSupport.QPrintPreviewDialog()
        dialog.paintRequested.connect(self.handlePaintRequest)
        dialog.exec_()

    def handlePaintRequest(self, printer):
        document = QtGui.QTextDocument()
#        document.setPlainText("Заголовок") # <-- нужно перенести наверх как заголовок
        # устанавливаем размер текста по умолчанию
#        font = QFont('Arial', 18)
        font = QFont('Arial', 27)
        document.setDefaultFont(font)
        cursor = QtGui.QTextCursor(document)

# +++          vvvvvvvvvv
        cursor.insertHtml('<h2 align="center" style="color: red;" >Заголовок<br></h2>')
        
        table = cursor.insertTable(self.tableWidget.rowCount(), 
                                   self.tableWidget.columnCount())
        for row in range(table.rows()):
            for col in range(table.columns()):
                it = self.tableWidget.item(row, col)
                if it is not None:

#                    cursor.insertText(it.text())
# +++                      vvvvvvvvvv
                    cursor.insertHtml(
                        f'<span style="color: blue;"><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;'
                        f'{it.text()}&nbsp;&nbsp;<br></span>')

                cursor.movePosition(QtGui.QTextCursor.NextCell)
        document.print_(printer)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ptw = PrintTableWidget()
    ptw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое, то что нужно!

Comment: @ДензаЧеловечище пожалуйста. Если мои ответы учат вас чему-то новому, не забывайте отмечать их и как полезные.